# String like text why returns false for following code?

Tags: c#, string

Why strLikeText is returns false for following code,

```
String s1 = "a"
string s2 = "ab"
bool b1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StringType.StrLikeText(s1,s2);
```

Comment: Why `Microsoft.VisualBasic` when the question is tagged by `C#`?

Comment: @AlexJolig How else you recommend to tag question about code in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Since `StrLikeText` Method Compares the parameters `Source` and `Pattern` and returns the same results as the Like operator, using text comparison.

Now your Source is `a` and pattern is `ab` which does not match. if you reverse the parameter it will return true.

Boolean value indicating whether or not the string satisfies the pattern. If the value in string satisfies the pattern contained in pattern, result is True. If the string does not satisfy the pattern, result is False.

Answer (score 0):

Here in code `s1` is your string source and `s2` is pattern so you have to use some pattern options [refer here](https://technet.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/library/swf8kaxw(v=vs.85)). It should be like

```
String s1 = "ab"
string s2 = "ab*"
bool b1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StringType.StrLikeText(s1,s2);
```

Source should be String to be match and Second one is like a general pattern which normally we use to compare.

Let me know if I am wrong this is what I got from the [reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.stringtype.strliketext(v=vs.85)?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp).